# Append Cells to Collection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, materialize

I currently am trying to simulate a mailbox and am using materialize in order to build it. Inside of my collection view, I am trying to add cells dynamically, but am unsure on how to proceed with appending html using Javascript.

```
  <div class="row" id="mailBox">
          <div class="container col s7">
            <div class="collection-header center">
              <h4>Email Box</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="collection with-header" id="mailCollection">
              <!-- Start: Trying to Dynamically Add These Cells To this view -->
              <li class="collection-item avatar email-unread">
                <span class="circle indigo darken-1"></span>
                <span class="email-title"> Subject </span>
                <p class="truncate grey-text ultra-small"> Message </p>
                <a href="#!" class="secondary-content email-time"><span class="blue-text ultra-small">Date Recieved</span></a>
              </li>
              <!-- End of Cell Content -->
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
```

I trying to append the collection items as such through my javascript, although nothing is appearing on the screen:

```
function createHTML(){
   var jsonData = jsonObject;
   for(var i =0; i < jsonData.length; i++){
     $("#mailCollection").append('<li class="collection-item avatar email-unread">' +
       '<span class="circle indigo darken-1"></span>'
       '<span class="email-title">' + jsonData[0]  + '</span>'
       '<p class="truncate grey-text ultra-small">' + jsonData[1] + '</p>'
       '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content email-time"><span class="blue-text ultra-small">' + jsonData[2] + '</span></a>
     </li>')
   }
 }
```

Comment: Any console errors? Does `jsonData` have a positive length?

Comment: The JSON data is printing out fine and has a length of 15, but the HTML is not populating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, There are so many syntax errors in single and double quotes where you append the html. Please check below code without any syntax error.

```js
function createHTML(){
   var jsonData = jsonObject;
   for(var i =0; i < jsonData.length; i++){
     $("#mailCollection").append("<li class='collection-item avatar email-unread'><span class='circle indigo darken-1'></span><span class='email-title'>' + jsonData[0]  + '</span><p class='truncate grey-text ultra-small'>' + jsonData[1] + '</p><a href='#!' class='secondary-content email-time'><span class='blue-text ultra-small'>' + jsonData[2] + '</span></a></li>")
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="mailBox">
          <div class="container col s7">
            <div class="collection-header center">
              <h4>Email Box</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="collection with-header" id="mailCollection">
              <!-- Start: Trying to Dynamically Add These Cells To this view -->
              <li class="collection-item avatar email-unread">
                <span class="circle indigo darken-1"></span>
                <span class="email-title"> Subject </span>
                <p class="truncate grey-text ultra-small"> Message </p>
                <a href="#!" class="secondary-content email-time"><span class="blue-text ultra-small">Date Recieved</span></a>
              </li>
              <!-- End of Cell Content -->
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
```